# How to solve Recurrence Relation with f(n) in it

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

This is the example:

```
T(1) = 1
f(n) = log2n
T(n) = a * T(n-1) + f(n)
```

I haven't solved ones with f(n) with them.
How exactly are they solved? Do you just switch f(n) with log2n or the solution is something else?

Comment: A valid step in a proof is replacing equals with equals. If f(n) = log2n and f(n) appears somewhere, it is valid to replace it with log2n. Whether that helps you solve something or not is not possible to say in general, but it's an obvious step. I'm not sure this is on-topic for stackoverflow, it seems you want help with basic maths and proofs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about programming or software engineering. Some questions about proofs of algorithms and their complexity can be on-topic here, but this is not specifically about algorithms, it's about basic methods of proof.

Comment: Thats about finding the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: I also voted to close down. You are asking a too broad question. You seem to want to solve non homogenous linear recurrences for which there are a lot of methods which are already probably discussed on mathoverflow (and if not there are countless papers online)